# How can I convert a dynamic web page to pdf?

Tags: html2pdf

I have a dynamic webpage that I created using html and php... I already have sample codes that can convert a static web page to pdf... But my problem is my web page is dynamic... So is there a way to convert my page to pdf?
Anyway, here is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once("../classes/Receipt.php");
    include_once("../classes/SalesDetail.php");
    include_once("../classes/Business.php");

    //session variable
    $userID = 1;

    $receipt = &new Receipt();
    $receipt->queryReceiptInfo($userID);
    $receiptID = $receipt->getReceiptID();
    $receiptIssueDate = $receipt->getReceiptIssueDate();
    $customer = $receipt->getCustomer();
    $salesID = $receipt->getSalesID();

    $salesDetail = &new SalesDetail($salesID);
    $salesDetails = $salesDetail->viewSalesDetail();

    //session variable
    $businessID = 1;
    $business = &new Business('', $businessID);
    $business->queryBusinessName();
    $businessName = $business->getBusinessName();

    $rows = sizeof($salesDetails);
    $columns = sizeof($salesDetails[0]);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Receipt No.</td>
        <td><?php echo $receiptID; ?></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date Issued</td>
        <td><?php echo $receiptIssueDate; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Business</td>
        <td><?php echo $businessName; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Customer</td>
        <td><?php echo $customer; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Sub-Total</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $totalPrice = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++) {
                echo "<td>".$salesDetails[$i][$j]."</td>";
            }
            $totalPrice += (double)$salesDetails[$i][2];
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total Price</td>
        <td><?php echo $totalPrice;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a PDF printer.

Is this for you to do on your own machine or as a server activity? If it's just for you, open the page in your favorite browser and print to PDF.

If it's for a server, try something like loading it in a browser control (easy with .net on windows, otherwise look at options using firefox components on linux) and get it to 'print' to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries which will allow ou to do this.

Start your research [here](http://www.macronimous.com/resources/Converting_HTML2PDF_using_PHP.asp) with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), and [HTML2FPDF](http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)